# How do I integrate Nancy with Autofac and ASP.NET Core windows service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, autofac, nancy

Let me try to keep it simple. My end goal is to create `windows service` using `asp.net core 2.1` and `Nancy` framework.

After lot of research i found below steps

1. Set up a Windows service - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-2.1
2. Hook up Nancy in to .net core application

**Problem Statement**

My Windows Service is using class libraries which are developed using `.net standard` and `Autofac` for DI.

Now how do I integrate `Autofac` instead of `Nancy's tiny IOC container`?

**I tried installing the nuget**

```
    Install-Package Nancy.Bootstrappers.Autofac -Version 2.0.0-clinteastwood
```

**And, wrote code as follow**

```
   protected override void ConfigureApplicationContainer(ILifetimeScope container)
   {

    _services.Configure<Settings>(_configuration.GetSection("MySettings"));
    var deviceId = _configuration["Settings:DeviceId"];

    var containerFactory = new ContainerFactory();

    container.Update(builder =>
    {
        builder.RegisterInstance(containerFactory).As<IContainerFactory>();
        containerBuilder.Register(c => new Engine(containerFactory));
        containerBuilder.Register(i => 
         new HubClient(deviceId, containerFactory))
          .As<HubClient>().SingleInstance();
    });
    base.ConfigureApplicationContainer(container);
}
```

**And, here I want to inject my class instances. but how?**

```
   public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var isService = !(Debugger.IsAttached || args.Contains("--console"));
        var builder = CreateWebHostBuilder(args.Where(arg => arg != "--console").ToArray());

        if (isService)
        {
            var pathToExe = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName;
            var pathToContentRoot = Path.GetDirectoryName(pathToExe);
            builder.UseContentRoot(pathToContentRoot);
        }

        var host = builder.Build();

        if (isService)
        {
            //this line fails
             IContainerFactory containerfactory = host.Services.GetService<IContainerFactory>();
            host.RunAsCustomService();
        }
        else
        {
            host.Run();
        }
    }
```

How do I get/inject **Engine** and **HubClient** instance?